# How to integrate MLKit (Selfie Segmentation) manually instead of cocoapod

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-mlkit

I want to integrate MLKit manually instead of cocoapod. I want to use MLKit Selfie Segmentation. Can someone please help me which frameworks do we need to add into the project for selfie segmentation. There is no such help on the site as the only way mention is to use cocoapod.

Comment: I am not sure what I am doing wrong while asking this question. There is no such help regarding manual integration of MLKit in your iOS project. I tried adding the frameworks manually but it gives me an error "Unable to install Appliation".

Comment: ML Kit is currently provided/supported only as cocoapods.  The "manual integration" you referenced is not supported, thus not mentioned on the ML Kit site.